# getting Error "Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using useRef() instead." React Native Expo App Although i am using useRef

Tags: react-native, expo, use-ref

```
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import BottomSheet, { BottomSheetFlatList } from "@gorhom/bottom-sheet";
export default function App() {
  // hooks
  const sheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);

  // variables
  const data = useMemo(
    () =>
      Array(50)
        .fill(0)
        .map((_, index) => `index-${index}`),
    []
  );
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ["25%", "50%", "90%"], []);

  // callbacks
  const handleSheetChange = useCallback((index) => {
    console.log("handleSheetChange", index);
  }, []);
  const handleSnapPress = useCallback((index) => {
    sheetRef.current?.snapToIndex(index);
  }, []);
  const handleClosePress = useCallback(() => {
    sheetRef.current?.close();
  }, []);

  // render
  const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({ item }) => (
      <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
        <Text>{item}</Text>
      </View>
    ),
    []
  );
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Snap To 90%" onPress={() => handleSnapPress(2)} />
      <Button title="Snap To 50%" onPress={() => handleSnapPress(1)} />
      <Button title="Snap To 25%" onPress={() => handleSnapPress(0)} />
      <Button title="Close" onPress={() => handleClosePress()} />
      <BottomSheet
        ref={sheetRef}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        onChange={handleSheetChange}
      >
        <BottomSheetFlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={(i) => i}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
        />
      </BottomSheet>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 200,
  },
  contentContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  itemContainer: {
    padding: 6,
    margin: 6,
    backgroundColor: "#eee",
  },
});
```

`I am getting this error`

Error: Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using useRef() instead. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-string-ref

This error is located at:
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent)

`i want to know where i have mistaken or is there any other steps need to be followed.`

Comment: please format your error instead of formatting text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const sheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet | null>(null);
```

Or

```
const sheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>();
```